# Cannot run : Unity Editor not found

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity. I can't run the project on MonoDevelop-Unity (On mac).

When I launch, I get "Unity Editor not found".

Comment: @UmaMadhavi how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: @cahen please check this link http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-basic.html

Comment: @UmaMadhavi you can run Unity3d applications almost anywhere, I always run in a Mac and once in a while test in a real device. The OP doesn't mention iOS in the question, but even if did, not being able to run in the iOS simulator is not the same as not being able to run a Unity3D application in a Mac.